How can I optimize my Flutter handwriting app that lags after writing for some time?
I'm trying to create a handwriting app using Flutter, I tried many different methods but I can't really find a way to optimize it: I reduced the amount of points take from the user's writing and I'm generating the line using circles and paths. I'm satisfied with the line smoothness but the app starts lagging after writing for some time.
This is my code:


import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'dart:math';

class Paper extends StatefulWidget {
  
  const Paper({super.key, required this.paperColor, required this.paperWidth, required this.paperHeight});

  final Color paperColor;
  final double paperWidth;
  final double paperHeight;

  @override
  State<Paper> createState() => _PaperState();
}

class _PaperState extends State<Paper> {

  final GlobalKey _painterKey = GlobalKey();

  List<StrokePath> _SPList = [];
  StrokePath _activeSP = StrokePath();

  bool _shouldRepaint = true;

  void calc_optimized(Point point) {

    if (point.getDistance() < 7 && point.getDistance() != 0 //|| 
            //point.getDeltaPressure() < 0.003 && point.getDeltaPressure() != 0 ||
            //point.getDeltaX() < 0.8 && point.getDeltaX() != 0 ||
            //point.getDeltaY() < 0.8 && point.getDeltaX() != 0 
    ) return;

    _activeSP.addPoint(point);
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      height: 1920,
      color: widget.paperColor,
      child: Listener(

        onPointerDown: (event) {
          _shouldRepaint = false;

          setState(() {
            
          });
        },
        onPointerMove: (event) {

          if (event.kind.name != "stylus") return;

          RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
          Offset position = renderBox.globalToLocal(event.position);

          Point point = Point(position: position, pressure: event.pressure, timestamp: event.timeStamp, lastPoint: _activeSP.lastPoint, isMiddle: false);

          calc_optimized(point);          

          /*debugPrint("-------- " + _activeSP.points.length.toString() + "--------");
          debugPrint("SPEED: " + point.getSpeed().toString());
          debugPrint("DISTANCE: " + point.getDistance().toString());
          debugPrint("DX: " + point.getDeltaX().toString());
          debugPrint("DY: " + point.getDeltaY().toString());
          debugPrint("DPRESS: " + point.getDeltaPressure().toString());
          debugPrint("-----------------------------------------------------------");*/

          setState(() {});
        },
        onPointerUp: (event) {
          _SPList.add(_activeSP);
          _activeSP = StrokePath();
          _shouldRepaint = true;

          setState(() {
            
          });
        },
            
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            RepaintBoundary(child: CustomPaint(painter: GridPainter(sqrWidth: 20, paperWidth: widget.paperWidth, paperHeight: widget.paperHeight))),
            CustomPaint(
              size: Size.infinite,
              painter: OldDrawing(pointsHistory: _SPList, rp: _shouldRepaint),
            ),
            RepaintBoundary(
              child: CustomPaint(
                size: Size.infinite,
                painter: Drawing(activePointsList: _activeSP.points, rp: _shouldRepaint),
                key: _painterKey,
              ),
            ),
          ]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// This draws a grid in the background
class GridPainter extends CustomPainter {

  GridPainter({required this.sqrWidth, required this.paperWidth, required this.paperHeight});

  double sqrWidth;
  double paperWidth;
  double paperHeight;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = const Color.fromARGB(154, 255, 255, 255)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    final divider = Paint();
    divider.color = Colors.white;
    divider.strokeWidth = 10;

    for (double x = sqrWidth; x < paperWidth; x += sqrWidth) {
      canvas.drawLine(Offset(x, 0), Offset(x, paperHeight), paint);
    }
    for (double y = sqrWidth; y <= paperHeight; y += sqrWidth) {
      canvas.drawLine(Offset(0, y), Offset(paperWidth, y), paint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}

// This should only repaint when the user finished to draw the actual line
class OldDrawing extends CustomPainter {

  OldDrawing({required this.pointsHistory, required this.rp});

  bool rp;
  List<StrokePath> pointsHistory;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {


    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 3;

    if (pointsHistory.isEmpty) return;

    for (StrokePath strokepath in pointsHistory) {
      
      if (strokepath.points.isNotEmpty) {

        List<Point> activePointsList = strokepath.points;
        if (activePointsList.isNotEmpty) {

          for (int i = 1; i < activePointsList.length; i++) {

            Path path = Path();

            Point p = activePointsList[i];
            Point last_p = activePointsList[i-1];

            canvas.drawCircle(p.position, p.getRadius(), paint);

            if (p.getDrawingDirection() != Offset.zero && last_p.getDrawingDirection() != Offset.zero) {
              /*
              for (Offset polPoint in p.getPolygonPoints()) {
                  canvas.drawCircle(polPoint, 1, paint2);
              }*/

              List<Offset> last_pPoints = last_p.getPolygonPoints();
              List<Offset> pPoints = p.getPolygonPoints();
              
              path.moveTo(last_pPoints[0].dx, last_pPoints[0].dy);

              path.lineTo(last_pPoints[1].dx, last_pPoints[1].dy);

              path.lineTo(pPoints[1].dx, pPoints[1].dy);

              path.lineTo(pPoints[0].dx, pPoints[0].dy);

              path.moveTo(last_pPoints[0].dx, last_pPoints[0].dy);

              path.close();

              canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return rp;
  }

}

// This should only draw the new line that the user is drawing
class Drawing extends CustomPainter {

  Drawing({required this.activePointsList, required this.rp});

  bool rp;
  List<Point> activePointsList;
  
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {

    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..strokeWidth = 3
      ..isAntiAlias = true;

      final paint2 = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.red
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..strokeWidth = 1
      ..isAntiAlias = true;

    if (activePointsList.isEmpty) return;

    for (int i = 1; i < activePointsList.length; i++) {

      Path path = Path();

      Point p = activePointsList[i];
      Point last_p = activePointsList[i-1];

      canvas.drawCircle(p.position, p.getRadius(), paint);

      if (p.getDrawingDirection() != Offset.zero && last_p.getDrawingDirection() != Offset.zero) {
        /*
        for (Offset polPoint in p.getPolygonPoints()) {
            canvas.drawCircle(polPoint, 1, paint2);
        }*/

        List<Offset> last_pPoints = last_p.getPolygonPoints();
        List<Offset> pPoints = p.getPolygonPoints();
        
        path.moveTo(last_pPoints[0].dx, last_pPoints[0].dy);

        path.lineTo(last_pPoints[1].dx, last_pPoints[1].dy);

        path.lineTo(pPoints[1].dx, pPoints[1].dy);

        path.lineTo(pPoints[0].dx, pPoints[0].dy);

        path.moveTo(last_pPoints[0].dx, last_pPoints[0].dy);

        path.close();

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}

class StrokePath {

  List<Point> points = [];

  void addPoint (Point point) {
    points.add(point);
  }

  Point? get lastPoint {
    return points.isNotEmpty ? points[points.length - 1] : null;
  }
}

// This class is used to get all the necessary data to optimize the points list
class Point {
  Point({required this.position, required this.pressure, required this.timestamp, required this.lastPoint, required this.isMiddle});

  bool isMiddle;

  Offset position;

  double pressure;

  Duration timestamp;
  Point? lastPoint;

  double getRadius() {
    return pressure * 5;
  }

  // Return the two points necessary to draw (for each couple of points) the polygon drawing that connects each couple of points
  List<Offset> getPolygonPoints() {

    if (lastPoint == null) return [];

    Offset ort = Offset(-getDrawingDirection().dy, getDrawingDirection().dx);
    double norm_ort = sqrt(ort.dx*ort.dx + ort.dy * ort.dy);
    Offset ort_normalized = Offset(ort.dx / norm_ort, ort.dy / norm_ort);
    
    return [position - ort_normalized * getRadius() * 1.1, position + ort_normalized * getRadius() * 1.1];
  }

  Offset getDrawingDirection() {
    if (lastPoint == null) return Offset.zero;

    return position - lastPoint!.position;
  }

  double getSpeed() {
    if (lastPoint == null) return 0;

    double distance = (position - lastPoint!.position).distance;
    Duration lastpointTimestamp = lastPoint!.timestamp;

    int dTime = timestamp.inMilliseconds - lastpointTimestamp.inMilliseconds;

    return distance / dTime;
  }

  double getDeltaX() {
    if (lastPoint == null) return 0;

    return (lastPoint!.position.dx - position.dx).abs();
  }

  double getDeltaY() {
    if (lastPoint == null) return 0;

    return (lastPoint!.position.dy - position.dy).abs();
  }

  double getDistance() {
    if (lastPoint == null) return 0;

    return (lastPoint!.position - position).distance.abs();
  }

  double getDeltaPressure() {
    if (lastPoint == null) return 0;

    return (lastPoint!.pressure - pressure).abs();
  }
}

I tried many handwriting apps on my tablet, they do not lag even if I draw a lot, do you have any suggestions?
